# Impact of Native English for writing content

Tags: user-engagement

My website caters to the US visitors. But I am from a different country. I try as much as possible to come up with decent English. However, I know for sure one can easily tell the difference by looking at the phrases used, choice of words, etc. Will it improve the user experience and engagement if I hire a US writer to rewrite my content?

Can native English writing improve user experience and/or engagement?

Comment: Use ChatGTP, it's really good at rewriting texts in English.

Comment: My larger question: Can native English writing improve user experience and/or engagement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially, yes but not necessarily for the reason you think.

If you know your audience then you can write for them in a more appealing way.

For instance, if your audience were young people working in the design industry then you might be ok addressing them by saying "Hey folks!" But, if your audience is the c-suite of a blue-chip business organisation, you might be better off addressing them with a more formal "Good afternoon."

This is known as "Tone of voice" or "Brand Language".

There are agencies that specialise in researching and developing guidelines for brands and products, creating rules on how to use language in specific ways to generate specific responses from your specific audience.

As someone already pointed out in the comments, if you know your demographics, you may be able to get ChatGPT to rewrite your text in a particular style and then test it with your audience.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! With the latest progression of technology, there are a lot of tools available to help you write good UX copy in English. I recommend trying Prowriting Figma plugin where you can transform a rough copy placeholder into a beautiful and ready-to-use UX copy. The product is equipped with proofreading feature as well to make sure all the writing is error-free.